# How to cancel 301 redirection on generated pages Nuxt

Tags: nuxt.js, single-page-application

*nuxt.config.js:*
...
`target: 'static',`
Then:
`npm run generate && npm run start`
In browser is typed `localhost:3000/alias`
In *DevTools>Network* I got:
`localhost:3000/alias  301`
`localhost:3000/alias/ 200`

How to get rid of 301 redirect to load straight url without trailing slash.
**Tip:** The page is absolutely static. All script files are removed on generate stage, so there are only html/css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on where you're hosting your app, but by default you should not have any redirection. Maybe double check your `nuxt.config.js` and look for the `trailingSlash` key.

Here is the behavior of this key: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-router#example-behavior-with-child-routes

Comment: A trailing Slash property doesn't make a redirect it only makes a rule of what version of url to load and which is to deny, with or without slash. So, your answer is correct partly, I suppose the catch is in a hosting, more specifically the point is in server settings.

Comment: Yep, I gave the 2 things that could lead to this kind of behavior. So, where do you host it?

Comment: I can't tell. My role consists on developing user interface. The question I've asked met the purpose to figure out a difficulty our team had faced. At the end a backend-magician has made her magic stuff and everything has become adjusted. Happyend!

Comment: @MaxS but don't you see the redirection still happens in devtools when you reload the page even though server side fixed the issue? 

DevTools>Network I got:
localhost:3000/alias  301
localhost:3000/alias/ 200
localhost:3000/alias 200
I am facing the same issue. can you help me?